# Only one div as xs resolution on lg

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I would like to get unusual behavior bootstrap and media-query.

The content of one div (a) should be dependent on his width and not the width of the browser window. In the case of the picture (a) has a width of 600px and should be displayed as XS, and the container should act as LG.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2gnr.png]

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of Bootstrap incorrectly.

The point of bootstrap is to allow you to easily modify the behavior of elements depending on the width of the screen. If you're using only the grid system for example, all you're modifying is the `width` of the elements themselves based on the `width` of the screen.

If you want your `a` element to behave as `sm` at all times, regardless of the width of the screen (or at least until it reaches `xs`, for example) then you can use something like:

```
 <div class=" div-a -col-sm-6"></div>
```

This will tell bootstrap to display the div A with 6 columns as long as the screen width is bigger than sm.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the container to act as LG" but I assume you mean it should be modified only for LG screens. Then:

```
<div class="container-div col-LG-12 col-*-newSize">
  <div class=" div-a -col-sm-6">
    *content*
  </div>
  <div class="container-b-c col-*-6"
    <div class"div-b col-*-12"
       -content-
    </div>
    <div class"div-c col-*-12"
       -content-
    </div>
 </div> //End of container-b-c
</div> //end of container-div
```

where * is the size you need.

Comment: I understand how the bootstrap. However, there is a new requirement, which requires such strange behavior. The whole page is to operate "normally", but one div must have determined rigidly 'resolution'.

Comment: Uhm I see. Maybe using manual media queries might be easier here rather than forcing bootstrap to behave in this way?

Comment: I still use the iframe, but I would prefer not to do